# Link to a page before launch

Tags: permalinks, pages

I have purchased my WordPress blog on BlueHost and it is not launched yet.

I would now like to link to the *About* and *Contact* pages that I have created from the *Home* page. When I look at the pages' permalinks, they are not based on my domain and have a temporary URLs e.g.  `http://box73873.temp.domains/[something]`.

Is it not possible to link to the pages before launch? Is there a certain format the page can have when the domain `www.mynewblog.com` goes public?

Comment: For this you have to add the rule in .htaccess file. It can be achievable by this.

Comment: @BaikareSandeep Could you be more specific?